# Регулярные выражения. Пересекающиеся последовательности

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Как из строки выбрать все необходимые последовательности, включая пересекающиеся?
Если делаю так:

```
re.findall('\d{3}', '123456')
```

то выдаёт: `['123', '456']`

Как сделать так, чтобы выдавал: `['123', '234', '345', '456']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо регулярных выражений для вашей проблемы:

```
In[65]: strng = '123456'
In[66]: [strng[i:i+3] for i in range(len(strng)-2)]
```

> ```
> Out[66]: ['123', '234', '345', '456']
> ```

Но когда вам с каких-то причин применить регулярное выражение, можете сделать так

```
In[67]: pattern = re.compile(r'\d{3}')
In[68]: [pattern.match(strng[i:]).group()  
   ...:     for i in range(len(strng)-1) if pattern.match(strng[i:])]
```

> ```
> Out[68]: ['123', '234', '345', '456']
> ```

Дело в том, что начинаем из целой строки и постепенно убираем из ней слева символы.